# Windows returns to the same exact state after reboot

Tags: windows, ssd, windows-11, docker-for-windows, splash

So, I'm using windows 11 on Lenovo Thinkpad E590. The problems started after installing **Docker desktop** and **Splash**. It was working just fine when suddenly blue screen of death appeared with syren like sound. After that,I can't do any changes on my pc. I can't install any software,to be precise it installs but doesn't open. I can't uninstall or delete anything,even if i succeed, they reappear after restart. I tried to format whole ssd with no success. **Diskpart** says that it succeeded in cleaning,but actually nothing happens. I've also tried **3rd party partition tools** using Hiren's boot but still no success. I've also tried **Lenovo Secure Wipe** from bios and it says it succeded but in reality it didn't. I've also tried **chkdsk** and it says no problems detected

Comment: This is a classic sign of a failed flash storage device. If you have an SSD then now is the time to copy off everything you can and replace the drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes i have ssd and probably I'll have to change it

Comment: Same thing happened to me - at some stage the SSD locked writes as it has a self protection mechanism which kicks in when things go wrong - recover what you can and get a Samsung SSD - Installed 100's and no failures. Worst are Sandisk and oddbrand chinese.

Comment: fortunately I don't have any important files on it. Thanks for the tip